# How can I downgrade Protocol buffer

Tags: downgrade

I need to install Protocol Buffer 2.4, but I happened to have installed 2.6 already. How can I downgrade?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably

```
make uninstall
```

the previous version (while inside the source folder). And then

```
make install
```

the new version.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways, in the folder of `Protocol Buffer 2.6` type the command:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

After, follow [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072683/how-can-i-install-protoc-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install version 2.4.
I hope it could be helpful!