# How can I install protoc on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

How can I install protoc, the protobuf compiler to generate Java, on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

See https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md:

### Prerequesites

```
$ sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool curl make g++ unzip
```

### Installation

1. From [this page](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases), download the `protobuf-all-[VERSION].tar.gz`.
2. Extract the contents and change in the directory
3. `./configure`
4. `make`
5. `make check`
6. `sudo make install`
7. `sudo ldconfig # refresh shared library cache.`

### Check if it works

```
$ protoc --version
libprotoc 3.6.1
```

Comment: The same steps works fine for Ubuntu Trusty too.

Comment: Also works on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EAFK-tN_yaw

Comment: step 4:
make -jX
Where X is number of cores you have, to run in parallel

Comment: perfect for Debian 10

Comment: thank @OmarS. it really used my 4 cores CPU to compile =))

Comment: @MartinThoma `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Bilal You probably didn't go into the directory. When you `ls`, can you see the file `configure`? If not, you did something wrong

Comment: @MartinThoma I went inside, I could see `configure.ac`, but I couldn't do `./configure`

Comment: @Bilal You need to [run autoconf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158961/4784). Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 57):

```
sudo apt install protobuf-compiler
```

Comment: It results in "Setting up protobuf-compiler (2.6.1-1.3)" - might not be the version everyone wants

Answer (score 12):

If you are a non-C++ user and/or don't want to compile it yourself, the simplest way to install the current version of protoc is to download a pre-built binary from the release page.

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases

To install, simply place this binary somewhere in your PATH (e.g. /usr/local/bin).

(If you intend to use the included well known types then don't forget to
copy the contents of the 'include' directory somewhere as well, for example
into /usr/local/include/.)

**Example:**

```bash
wget https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v21.12/protoc-21.12-linux-x86_64.zip
sudo unzip -o protoc-21.12-linux-x86_64.zip -d /usr/local bin/protoc
sudo unzip -o protoc-21.12-linux-x86_64.zip -d /usr/local 'include/*'
# now test:
protoc --version
```

Comment: You may also need some protos from [Google's Common API](https://github.com/googleapis/api-common-protos/tree/master/google/api) protos. Clone [the repo][4] and move the contents of `google` to  `/usr/local/include/`.

Comment: protoc is not looking in /usr/local/include for me, at least by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can download binary from the source code and use next commands

```
sudo rm -rf ./protoc
unzip protoc-3.10.1-linux-x86_64.zip -d protoc
chmod 755 -R protoc
BASE=/usr/local
sudo rm -rf $BASE/include/google/protobuf/
sudo cp protoc/bin/protoc $BASE/bin 
sudo cp -R protoc/include/* $BASE/include
```

Change your base to /usr/, or /usr/loca/, or anything else in your PATH.

Answer (score 2):

Use this if you are having errors like

> google/protobuf/descriptor.proto: File not found.
> google/protobuf/duration.proto: File not found.
> google/protobuf/timestamp.proto: File not found.

```
PROTOC_ZIP=protoc-3.7.1-linux-x86_64.zip
curl -OL https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.7.1/$PROTOC_ZIP
sudo unzip -o $PROTOC_ZIP -d /usr/local bin/protoc
sudo unzip -o $PROTOC_ZIP -d /usr/local 'include/*'
rm -f $PROTOC_ZIP
```

This is useful when you are doing generation for go using protoc-gen-go as it requires the base proto files to be present in default include folders

Answer (score 1):

1) Download binary from the url  https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases

2) extract and keep the directory at particular location (/user/app/protoc)

3) add the entry in /usr//.bash_profile as 
`export PROTOC_HOME=/user/app/protoc
export PATH=$PROTOC_HOME/bin:$PATH`

4) refresh file  `$source /usr/<username>/.bash_profile`

Other option is run the following command one by one after downloading the repository :

`sudo rm -rf ./protoc`

`unzip protoc-3.10.1-linux-x86_64.zip -d protoc`

`chmod 755 -R protoc`

`BASE=/usr/local`

`sudo rm -rf $BASE/include/google/protobuf/`

`sudo cp protoc/bin/protoc $BASE/bin`

`sudo cp -R protoc/include/* $BASE/include`