# Protobuf installation fails due to version mismatch of Automake

Tags: 16.04, automake

I was following the answer on: [How can I install protoc on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072683/how-can-i-install-protoc-on-ubuntu-16-04)

But, my protobuf installation `make` fails with versioning issue in Automake

```
/protobuf/missing automake-1.15 --foreign
configure.ac:48: error: version mismatch.  This is Automake 1.15,
configure.ac:48: but the definition used by this AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
configure.ac:48: comes from Automake 1.15.1.  You should recreate
configure.ac:48: aclocal.m4 with aclocal and run automake again.
WARNING: 'automake-1.15' is probably too old.
         You should only need it if you modified 'Makefile.am' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'automake' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/>
Makefile:1451: recipe for target 'Makefile.in' failed
make: *** [Makefile.in] Error 1
```

Comment: I'm curious why `make` would even need to invoke `automake` here - that should only happen if the `configure` script became out-of-date (for example, if `configure.ac` was changed after you ran `./configure`). Perhaps it would be useful to add the output of `ls -l config*` to your question so we can see the timestamps?

Comment: `ls -l config*` output :   
 ```vagrant@net1mc2:~/temp$ ls -l config*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  43815 Jul 30  2018 config.guess
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   3846 Jul 30  2018 config.h.in
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  36692 Jul 30  2018 config.sub
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 723617 Jul 30  2018 configure
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   7158 Jul 30  2018 configure.ac
```

Comment: I could not get it to work on Linux, as I had shortage of time. So, I just installed protobuf on my Windows OS, and got to use the protoc command line. Using protoc command was my end goal in this case. But, yes, that doesn't solve my question.